connect private messaging endpoint to teams bot
I created a Teams chat bot using botframework and want to test it out from teams. I made an Azure Bot and set the messaging endpoint to a valid https url that points to my app. It looks like when you send a message, Teams makes a request to a public url, https://teams.microsoft.com, that fails. I presume this has no way of knowing about the company lan. How do I expose my bot without exposing it publicly?

To expose your bot without making it publicly accessible, you can use tunneling software like ngrok to create an externally addressable URL for a port opened locally on your machine. This allows you to test your bot in Teams without exposing it to the public internet. Install and Setup ngrok. Update the messaging endpoint for your bot in the Bot Framework portal to use the ngrok URL. For example, https://ad6524fb.ngrok.io/api/messages.

Test your bot in Teams by sending messages. Teams will now make requests to the ngrok URL, which will tunnel the requests to your locally running bot.

The whole point of a tunneling tool like ngrok IS to make the endpoint available on the public internet!

In simple terms, this is not possible - a Teams bot, being based on the Microsoft Bot Framework, MUST be accessible on the internet, and via an httpS endpoint. However, that endpoint is never EXPOSED to anyone at all (it's bound only between Microsoft's Bot Framework and your internal address). That said, you might need help to get a locally-hosted bot accessible from the outside internet, and a "Tunneling" tool can help with this. There are a few options:

NGrok is a well-known tool for doing this - it's got a free version, but for "live" (non development) hosting, you'll need a paid license
CloudFlare have a tunnelling option that's free
Microsoft have a (relatively new) "Dev Tunneling" capability - see more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/dev-tunnels/overview

In terms of security though, there are various elements to consider and protections you can put in place. For instance, it's possible to block calls from any but your own specific company Microsoft 365 tenant, and the easiest way to do this is via "bot middleware". It's also possibly to enforce SSO, especially if you want the bot to do so something on behalf of a specific user. You can read more about those in a previous answer I posted on this site, at Single Tenant Teams Bot Authentication Error: Missing access_token.

How is it not exposed to anyone if its publicly available?

well, there's a difference between 'available' and 'advertised' - it's never listed or published anywhere publicly that anyone would stumble upon, which lowers the risk. Also, the tunnel endpoint when using ngrok, for example, is a random generated url that is unique every time, so when you shut it down it's completely destroyed in any case. I certainly wouldn't recommend tunneling for a production scenario though, unless there's a very specific reason and scenario.

Right but if I'm creating something that will end up in production, I won't be using NGrok.

Good plan. Your original question was about "testing" it though - for dev/testing, NGrok or similar are fine
